# Docusign recipientid changes after sending

Tags: docusignapi

I added 2 recipients to an envelope via the api i gave them recipient ids of '111' & '222' respectively. I pre-populated the tags associated with them. The envelopes, when received for signature, were populated as expected, but When I examined the completed envelope to retrieve the tab data, the ids for the recipients were '1' and '6'. Am I doing something wrong. I am using the docusign-csharp-client.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's expected behavior. The recipient ids are for use within the request or response bodies to associate a given recipient with related information.

If you want to store your own data in the enveloper for later retrieval, use custom fields. Refer to the recipients by their email + name to ensure specificity.

(Two people can share the same email, eg husband and wife are two different people and two different signatures but might be sharing a common email.)